# Why is my attempt to install Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 10 (manta) blocking?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-10

On [the instructions for installing Ubuntu on Android hardware](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) (I have a new Nexus 10 32G wireless), I'm at the step of installation that says:

> Install Ubuntu using your selected channel, in this case we use the devel channel:
>
> $ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap

The output for this last command is:

```
2015/12/26 10:29:02 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/12/26 10:29:03 Device is |manta|
Device manta not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu
```

What can/should I change in the command (or anything else I'm giving) to let Ubuntu install?

--UPDATE--

The bootloader screen says:
`DEVICE INFORMATION
PRODUCT NAME: manta
VARIANT: wifi
H/W VERSION: 8
BOOTLOADER VERSION: MANTALJ12
CARRIER INFO: NONE
SERIAL NUMBER: A3203044V1A
LOCK STATE: UNLOCKED
REBOOT MODE FLAG: NONE
FASTBOOT STATUS - OKAYmanta`

When I switch from `stable` to `devel`, I received a different error, stating apparently that permission was denied to create `/root/.cache` (`/root/.cache` on the Android device? `/root` on my Ubuntu machine is mode 700 root:root, and I'm trying to run the command as root):
`root@ubuntu:/home/christos# ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu --bootstrap
2015/12/26 12:10:40 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/12/26 12:10:40 Device is |manta|
2015/12/26 12:10:40 Flashing version 2 from ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device manta
2015/12/26 12:10:40 mkdir /root/.cache: permission denied`

I tried the same from an unprivileged account and it appeared to flash:
`christos@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu --bootstrap
2015/12/26 12:17:43 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2015/12/26 12:17:43 Device is |manta|
2015/12/26 12:17:43 Flashing version 2 from ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device manta
3.95 MB / 3.95 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 860.48 KB/s
36.83 MB / 36.83 MB [======================================] 100.00 % 2.18 MB/s
332.41 MB / 332.41 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 5.23 MB/s
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Start pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Start pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu/manta/version-2.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Start pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Start pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-6d69386203f3e45348aba79e08b7176c38499e1da5a68af5d3fbabc2ac2b6cb2.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Start pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-69b152491e6a57ef9672230f4220155bbb17755645824e02e9515a44d7dc8ee2.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Start pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-631ce387d6c729c3da0ae9177d0c9d9a07f3e0dfb15b21b20771079322915d20.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:09 Done pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:10 Done pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:10 Done pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu/manta/version-2.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:19:18 Done pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-6d69386203f3e45348aba79e08b7176c38499e1da5a68af5d3fbabc2ac2b6cb2.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:20:03 Done pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-69b152491e6a57ef9672230f4220155bbb17755645824e02e9515a44d7dc8ee2.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:23:42 Done pushing /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-631ce387d6c729c3da0ae9177d0c9d9a07f3e0dfb15b21b20771079322915d20.tar.xz to device
2015/12/26 12:23:42 Created ubuntu_command: /home/christos/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands775353844
2015/12/26 12:23:43 Rebooting into recovery to flash`

However, on boot, the screen shows "Google", then very briefly displays the Ubuntu logo, then gives a logo of a microchip across a red octagon / X, and says in a few languages, "This phone needs restoring from a PC or service center."

Advice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the first problem of not finding stable manta. That's because it doesn't exist. You can search with ubuntu-flash-device query like this.

```
> ubuntu-device-flash query --list-channels --device=manta
ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed/ubuntu
ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu
ubuntu-touch/devel/krillin.en
>
```

You can also browse the server at https://system-image.ubuntu.com/.

I installed from the devel channel, which is at least running. Still figuring out how well it works.